# How do I get a custom hook in react to load first and then use setInterval to run every 4 sec?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

How do I get the action to run first so it loads when the page loads and then interval every 4 sec? Currently when the page loads the `dencrypt` waits 4 sec and then works fine as it repeats

```
   const Home = () => {
    const { result, dencrypt } = useDencrypt();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let i = 0;
        const action = setInterval(() => {
            dencrypt(values[i]);
        i = i === values.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
        }, 4000);

        return () => clearInterval(action);
  }, []);
```

Comment: What is your question again??

Comment: How do I get the action to run first so it loads when the page loads and then interval every 4 sec.  currently when the page loads the decrypt waits 4 sec and then works fine as it repeats.

Comment: I was thinking I need to call the function when the component loads, but im not sure how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const functionToSet = () => {
        console.log("Run");
    };
    functionToSet();

    const timerID = setInterval(functionToSet, 4000);

    return () => clearInterval(timerID);
}, []);
```

Comment: Awesome.. thank you.  I have been working on this for hours!